# crash log showing a call stack that doesn't occur

Tags: ios, swift, realm

Here's section of a .crash file

```
Thread 0 name:
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018181d2ec __pthread_kill + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001819be288 pthread_kill$VARIANT$mp + 376 (pthread.c:1484)
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x000000018178bd0c abort + 140 (abort.c:91)
3   libc++abi.dylib                 0x0000000180f272c8 abort_message + 132 (abort_message.cpp:75)
4   libc++abi.dylib                 0x0000000180f27470 default_terminate_handler() + 304 (cxa_default_handlers.cpp:68)
5   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x0000000180f508d4 _objc_terminate() + 124 (objc-exception.mm:657)
6   libc++abi.dylib                 0x0000000180f4137c std::__terminate(void (*)()) + 16 (cxa_handlers.cpp:66)
7   libc++abi.dylib                 0x0000000180f40ccc __cxa_throw + 132 (cxa_exception.cpp:130)
8   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x0000000180f50720 objc_exception_throw + 364 (objc-exception.mm:547)
9   Realm                           0x00000001029405f0 -[RLMRealm verifyThread] + 80 (RLMRealm.mm:152)
10  Realm                           0x00000001028c8a78 invocation function for block in objc_object* (anonymous namespace)::makeBoxedGetter<realm::StringData>(unsigned long) + 80 (RLMObject_Private.hpp:47)
11  My App                  0x00000001025ab94c CallerDetailViewController.getTitleOfCaller() + 64 (CallerDetailViewController.swift:1864)
12  My App                  0x00000001025b4db8 specialized CallerDetailViewController.displayUnableToMarkAsNotSpamErrorMessage(error:) + 48
13  My App                  0x00000001025b5684 specialized closure #2 in closure #2 in CallerDetailViewController.blockNumber() + 100 (CallerDetailViewController.swift:0)
14  My App                  0x00000001025b809c partial apply for closure #2 in closure #2 in CallerDetailViewController.blockNumber() + 176 (CallerDetailViewController.swift:0)
15  My App                  0x0000000102629b7c thunk for @callee_owned () -> () + 36 (Toast.swift:0)
16  libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000181688aa0 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 24 (init.c:994)
```

However this stack track is something which just doesn't occur in the app - the method blockNumber() does not call the method displayUnableToMarkAsNotSpamErrorMessage(), nor does it call any method that does (nor is there any swizzling etc. going on). How can the crash stack show a method call stack that doesn't exist?

```
func blockNumber()
{
    Model.log("CallerDetailViewController:blockNumber()")
    if editActionIsInProgress == true
    {
        return
    }
    var op : UsageStats.Op = UsageStats.Op("IOS-VZ-UI-\(self.VCNAME)-BLOCKEXISTING")
    let mdnToBlock = self.caller!.number
    editActionIsInProgress = true
    RootNavigationController.displayActivityIndicator(message: NSLocalizedString("VC_CALLER_DETAIL_BLOCKING_IN_PROGRESS", comment: ""))
    if isExistingCaller
    {
        Model.instance().robocallerManager().blockExistingCaller(mdn: mdnToBlock) {(error) -> Void in
            Model.log("CallerDetailViewController:blocExistingCaller() completion")
            self.editActionIsInProgress = false
            RootNavigationController.hideActivityIndicator  { () in
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    if error == nil
                    {
                        self.displayBlockedConfirmationMessage()
                        self.displayGUIBasedOnCategory()
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        let err = error! as NSError
                        self.displayUnableToUnblockErrorMessage(error: err)
                        let _ = op.withError(error!)
                    }
                    UsageStats.collectUIStatistics(op)
                }
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        let mdn = caller?.number
        var op : UsageStats.Op = UsageStats.Op("IOS-VZ-UI-\(self.VCNAME)-BLOCKNEW")

        // disable the block button in the popup until the operation has completed to prevent user's from
        // tapping it twice
        Model.instance().robocallerManager().blockNewCaller(caller: caller!, completion: { (error) in
            Model.log("CallerDetailViewController:blockNewCaller() completion")
            self.editActionIsInProgress = false
            RootNavigationController.hideActivityIndicator(completion: {})
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                if error == nil
                {
                    // Fetch the newly added Realm managed object within the main thread to ensure the realm is the one for the main thread
                    self.caller = Model.instance().database().findCaller(mdn: mdn!)
                    self.isExistingCaller = true
                    self.addRealmNotification()
                    self.displayBlockedConfirmationMessage()
                    self.displayGUIBasedOnCategory()
                }
                else
                {
                    let err = error! as NSError
                    self.displayUnableToUnblockErrorMessage(error: err)
                    let _ = op.withError(error!)
                }
                UsageStats.collectUIStatistics(op)
            }
        })
    }
}


func displayUnableToMarkAsNotSpamErrorMessage(error:Swift.Error)
{
    var message = self.getTitleOfCaller()
    message = message + " - " + (self.caller?.number.formatPhoneNumberForDisplay())! + " " + NSLocalizedString("VC_CALLER_DETAIL_UNABLE_TO_MARK_AS_NOT_SPAM", comment: "")
    RootNavigationController.displayErrorDialog(title: message, err: error as NSError)
}
```

Comment: It is not `blockCaller()` according to the crash report it is `blockNumber()`

Comment: @Oscar Apepland I have spent days reading crash tutorials without result. That is the reason for the questions as they have not helped.

Comment: "the method blockNumber() does not call the method displayUnableToMarkAsNotSpamErrorMessage()" Clearly it _does_. Is there a completion handler being passed around here?

Comment: @matt. No there isn't. I think I may know what could be going on perhaps. blockNumber() is not being called and there are no completion handlers involved. However a similar method to blockNumber is being called; there are 5 methods with different names, each with similar content apart from a localizable string which is different in each. Perhaps the compiler has optimized these methods into one so that is why it appears this way in the stack, does that sound feasible?

Comment: Sounds like flimflam to me. I think it’s more likely that you have a threading issue and this view controller is being mishandled somehow, and the situation you’re seeing is diagnostic of a mistake that happened earlier. As you’ve been rightly told, the question to ask yourself is why Realm thinks you’re on the wrong thread.

Comment: Without actual code of `CallerDetailViewController` it is hard to say why you see this crash report

Answer (score 0):

I don't actually think `CallerDetailViewController.displayUnableToMarkAsNotSpamErrorMessage` is being called. You'll notice there's no symbolicated execution line at the end of its placement in the stack trace.

I have a few guesses what might be going on here, but without actually looking at your code or understanding what any of these methods actually are I can't say for certain why it appears in the stack trace at that point.

Answer (score -1):

According to your crash log, the code in the **getTitleOfCaller** function of the class **CallerDetailViewController** is causing the crash. The fact that the crash is occurring in RLMRealm’s **verifyThread** function is telling me that you are trying to access a realm object on a different thread. This is not allowed in Realm, as objects are thread confined.

You can check out [Realm’s documentation on how to fix this.](https://realm.io/docs/objc/latest/#passing-instances-across-threads)

Comment: Thank you, yes I know the crash is occuring in getTitleOfCaller, and I know about thread issues with Realm. My question however is specifically about why is the call stack showing a call sequence that just doesn't occur.

Comment: Well, it certainly seems to occur, since you are getting the crash. Try adding a break point in the displayUnableToMarkAsNotSpamErrorMessage function and see what happens.